# Quantidade de linhas e colunas de uma matriz em python

Tags: python, matriz

Como faço para saber a quantidade de linhas e de colunas de uma matriz na linguagem Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depende do que você quer dizer com "matriz": A linguagem python em si, pura, não tem uma estrutura específica para matriz. Pode se usar listas dentro de listas, mas não existe uma forma de determinar o tamanho sem iterar e contar elementos de cada lista.

Uma alternativa muito comum para manipulação de matrizes é a biblioteca **numpy**. Ela não faz parte do python e precisa ser instalada separadamente, porém, facilita muito o uso de matrizes e suas operações. Se estiver usando numpy, pode usar o atributo `shape`:

```
import numpy
m = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [10, 15, 20]])
print(m.shape)
```

Isso vai imprimir as dimensões da matriz do numpy (chamada de array):

```
(2, 3)
```